# Trying to get absolute Url from string?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have the following url as a string

`/Users/username/Documents/`

and I need to convert it to

`file:///localhost/Users/username/Documents/`

So I can use it as a path argument in an NSOpenPanel. But I can't figure out how to do it? Is there any method? I know how to go from absolute -> normal, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need fileURLWithPath like this:

```
[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/username/Documents/"];
```